# Generating HTTP errors using Fat-Free-Framework

Tags: php, mysql, fat-free-framework

I am using fat-free framework for my Rest API. I have a unique constraint on one of my database field. My question is how can i trigger a proper HTTP error based on mysql duplicate entry error.

Following is my insert function

```
    $username = $f3->get('username');
    $status=$GLOBALS['db']->exec('INSERT INTO Users 
                     VALUES(:userID,:username)',
                     array(':userID'=>'',':username'=>$username));

    header('Content-Type: application/json');                                                                   
    return (json_encode($status));
```

My insert statement triggers following error based on unique constraint on field

```
Internal Server Error
PDOStatement: Duplicate entry 'someUserName' for key 'username'
```

I want to trigger HTTP error because on the client side i can handle HTTP errors.
Please guide me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a try / catch statement and call `$f3->error('400','MSG')` to send one of your favorite http status codes and trigger the ONERROR handler,
If you like to only send the status code header, you can use the `$f3->status` method

Answer (score 0):

Try to see this documntation : http://fatfreeframework.com/framework-variables#about-the-f3-error-handler